# How to add (concatenate) to an existing PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

Would this work? I know you can concatenate variables this way.

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          $recipients[] = $row['phone'] . $row['carrier'];
    }

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $recipients[] .= $row['email'];
    }
```

Comment: @Jack  Yes, it does work in fact! But I feel like it's  bad practice and got good ideas below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work since you have already reached the end of the fetch (i.e. `mysql_fetch_array` will always return false in the second loop).

Moreover, it probably wouldn't be a good idea if you wanted have some indicator of phone vs. email, but I guess you don't:

```
$phones = array();
$emails = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $phones[] = $row['phone'] . $row['carrier'];
   $emails[] = $row['email'];
}
$recipients = $phones + $emails;
```

Also, didn't anyone tell you to use `PDO` or `mysqli`?

Comment: Yes, I will be converting to mysqli.  I'm late ;)

Comment: Also, I like your answer.  That looks good!  My code worked, but this look more efficient.

Comment: Okay -- anyone reading this should apparently know that you can use `mysql_fetch_array` twice in a row!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have two separate queries and they both return the same number of results in the *exact* same order, you should use a counter to help you find the right entry to modify:

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $recipients[$i++] .= $row['email'];
}
```